# Disable drag and drop for only one row in Handsontable grid

Tags: handsontable

I am new to [Handsontable](https://handsontable.com/).

I am working on the drag and drop feature.

I am able to enable drag and drop by setting the 'manualRowMove' property to true.

However, I want to *disable* drag and drop on just the *last* row.

**Question**: Is there any way to achieve this?

I have checked their documentation and online forums but did not find an answer.

**Handsontable code**:

```
table = new Handsontable(container1, {
        data: data,
        defaultRowHeight: 20,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        manualRowMove: true, 
        licenseKey: LicenseKey, 
        colHeaders: ["Name", "Email", "Designation", "Id"], 
        columns: [
            { data: "Name", type: "text", readOnly: true },
            { data: "Email", type: "text", readOnly: false },
            { data: "Designation", type: "text", readOnly: false },
            { data: "Id", type: "text", readOnly: true }
        ]        
    });
```

Comment: perhaps try here: https://forum.handsontable.com/

Comment: why your question is tagged `c#`? handsontable is a js library..